# Understanding simple Counter code

Tags: java, counter

I am taking a Java course for beginners at university and I am confused how does it compile/execute
following is code:

```
public class Counter {
    private int counter;
    private int end;

    public Counter(int start, int end) {
        this.counter = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "[Counter counter=" + counter + " end=" + end + "]";
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void count(int increment) {
        if (counter < end) {
            counter += increment;
        }
    }

    public void count() {
        count(1);
    }
}
```

Other class

```
public class CounterProgram {

    private Counter counter;

    public void init() {
        counter = new Counter(1, 3);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter.count();
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter.count();
        System.out.println(counter);
        counter.count();
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CounterProgram counterProgram = new CounterProgram();
        counterProgram.init();
        counterProgram.run();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what `count(1)` means in the method `public void count` can anyone explain? Thank you for your time!

Comment: It calls `public void count(int increment)`. Read a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) please.

Answer (score 4):

`count(1)` is a call to the `count` method with argument `1` (`int`):

```
public void count(int increment)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `count()` methods in your `Counter` class, each with different arguments. One of them is generic; it can add a given increment value to the value of the internal `counter` variable. The other one is specific in the sense that it is supposed to increment the `counter` by just `1`.

So, your `public void counter()` method can make use of the more generic `public void counter (int increment)`, by calling it, instead of re-implementing its own logic.

In other words, your `counter()` method is calling `counter (int increment)` to avoid code repetition, which is an extremely important thing in good quality code.

Answer (score 0):

`count(1)` calls the `overloaded` method `count(int increment)`, which increments counter value by 1 if counter is less than `end`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in java, I suggest consider your-self compiler. if you are using any IDE like NetBeans or you can run in debug mode.
For this code:

1. First `public static void main(String[] args)` as every program runs from main method.
2. Second creating an object of class `CounterProgram counterProgram = new CounterProgram();` on right and side `new CounterProgram();` calls the constructor of class which is empty because not defined
3. Third `init` initilize count values
4. Forth `run()` now in run method there are multiple commands you can do demonstration on page. It is increment only with condition `<end`